# What is this usage of "that" in "Oh, that I have never allowed myself to be made king!'?

Tags: word-usage

The snail offered to take Doctor Dolittle and his friends all back to England inside his shell.

> "Goodness, what a chance, I'd love to go. To examine the floor of the
>   ocean all the way from Brazil to Europe. No man ever did it before.
>   What a glorious trip. Oh, **that** I have never allowed myself to be made
>   king! Now I must see the chance of a lifetime slip by."

This is from a novel "The Voyages of Doctor Dolittle". What is this usage of this "that"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your context **that** is used as a conjunction.

According to the [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/that), definition #4, when used as a conjunction:

> Used to introduce an elliptical exclamation of desire: Oh, that I were rich!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I understand it don't have the meaning? And is this usage of "that" common?

Comment: I think **that** writers are more likely to use it in their literary works. In conversation, many people would say: *Oh, I wish I were rich!*, @YuuichiTam.